# How to filter content in views based on user id

Tags: views, entities, users

Is there a way to for a normal user (without admin power) to set permissions for a specific piece of content (not a content type) so that it is only visible to a specific user? I want it so that said specific user can see content that has been specifically assigned to them in a table in a view.

Comment: I tried making using a select list with names of users so that a name could be selected and assigned for a certain content type. I then edited the view for the specific user so that it would filter content based on what name was assigned, but I realized that since the view was for everyone in a certain role, I couldn't users see only content that was assigned to them specifically. @keithm

Comment: Welcome  to Drupal Answers! What do you mean by _a specific piece of content_?

Comment: By specific piece of content  mean, for example, Basic Page A, instead of just basic pages in general. @kiamlaluno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using these modules:

- If you want to give permissions to node then you can use this module

  [Node Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess)

> Nodeaccess is a Drupal access control module which provides view, edit
>   and delete access to nodes. Users with the 'grant node permissions'
>   permission will have a grant tab on node pages which allows them to
>   grant access to that node by user or role. Administrators can set
>   default access controls per content type, and also define which roles
>   are available to grant permissions to on the node grants tab.

- If you want to "assign" node to some user, you can use user reference field and then in view add filter for that field and make it filter by current user.

For user reference use this field

[References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references)

> There were a couple changes in the way 'References' views are handled
>   ("referenceable nodes/users defined by a view"), which might require
>   double-checking those existing on your site:
>
> - The 'label' (node title or user name) is no longer automatically    added if not included in the view. If some of your 'References' views 
>     currently do not include it, you might want to add it explicitly,
>     else it will no longer appear in the widgets.
> - The HTML generated by the view is no longer stripped out before being    handed to "checkboxes / radios" widgets, thus allowing
>     advanced    formatting. You might want to check for Reference views
>     having fields    configured to display "as links", since the (probably
>     unwanted)     tags generated by Views are not removed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen **Field Permissions** module ?
visit https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions

by this module, you can add permissions to fields in order to visible/invisible part of content type.